# Use FFMpeg with pure php and shared hosting

Tags: php, ffmpeg, ffmpeg-php

So I want to use [FFMpeg](https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg) library and found standalone PHP version, I used this before on Laravel and installed composer but now in this case, I am trying to install this library on a shared hosting, I just upload src folder and start with this:

```
<?php
$ffmpeg = FFMpeg\FFMpeg::create(array(
    'ffmpeg.binaries'  => 'FFMpeg/FFMpeg.php', 
    'ffprobe.binaries' => 'FFMpeg/FFProbe.php', 
    'timeout'          => 3600,
    'ffmpeg.threads'   => 12,  
));
$video = $ffmpeg->open('video.mpg');
?>
```

But got error:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Class 'FFMpeg\FFMpeg' not found
>   in...

So how can I use `FFMpeg` on a shared hosting and install it manually (without composer)

Comment: I hear you. When I asked about usage without Composer, for another library, I didn't receive much help. The problem is that composer does a lot in the background. It loads dependencies, sets up the class loader, and more. Once a library has gone the composer way the developers feel no need to support a manual install anymore. In an euphemistic way they will say that using composer is the 'recommended' or 'easiest' way to use their library. That said, any library can be used without composer, but it can be an effort to get it all working. See: https://github.com/PHP-FFMpeg/PHP-FFMpeg/issues/382

Comment: @KIKOSoftware The problem is I can't install composer on a shared hosting, so I can't use composer and have to do this manually, so I should give up on this, right?

Comment: I didn't say that. I've got some libraries working without composer, but as I said, it can be an effort. What I meant is that you should expect any help. Most people love composer, and they can't imagine you wouldn't want to, or can't, use it.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Composer free solution, but if you upload `vendor` (created by Composer) as well as your source and add:

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';
```

to the head of the script (ensuring that the path is relative to the current script) it should be able to resolve the `FFMpeg\FFMpeg` class.

I'd suggest this is preferable as there are dependencies that `PHP-FFMpeg` has that you would also need to include, and Composer takes care of that.

Comment: I'll try your solution

Comment: Yes, this is not a bad idea in this case. Have one server with Composer and make it all work, and then simply copy over all the 'verndor' PHP scripts to the server without Composer. That should work.

Comment: How can I find this `autoload.php` file? I couldn't find this in composer website

Comment: It should be under `vendor` if you've run `composer install` or if you've run `composer dumpautoload`.